# SQL that counts from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I am managing a database for a social network where users can like, comment and I created a table each for the post, like, and comments.

```
like --- post_id
         user_id

comment --- post_id
            user_id
```

Now when I run `select * from post`, I want to be able to add a two columns `likes` and `comments` that counts the number of likes and comments having each `post_id`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to join to both tables.

```
SELECT post.*, COUNT(likes.id) AS like_count, COUNT(comment.id) AS comment_count
FROM post
    LEFT JOIN likes ON post.id = likes.post_id
    LEFT JOIN comment ON post.id = comment.post_id
GROUP BY post.id
```

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
SELECT *
,    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE post_id=p.id) as LIKE_COUNT
,    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment WHERE post_id=p.id) as COMMENT_COUNT
FROM post p
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d26b1/1)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT post.id, COUNT(like.id) AS like_count, COUNT(comment.id) AS comment_count
FROM post p
    LEFT JOIN like ON post.id = like.post_id
    LEFT JOIN comment ON post.id = comment.post_id
GROUP BY post.id
```

It's like answer of [@Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163495/richard) but modifying the `select`, because the column in `group by` must be in the `select` clause.

Comment: Under SQL Server I would agree - however, MySQL is a lot less strict about naming all of the SELECT fields in GROUP BY.  You can group by the primary key, and still SELECT * from that table.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it. Nice comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  post.*,
  IFNULL(COUNT(like.user_id),0) AS likecount,
  IFNULL(COUNT(comment.user_id),0) AS commentcount
FROM
  post
  LEFT JOIN like ON post.post_id=like.post_id
  LEFT JOIN comment ON post.post_id=comment.post_id
GROUP BY
  like.post_id
```